# Suitable monitors to use with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: usb, screen

I bought my son a 'starter' bundle, minus USB hub and monitor. Are any suitable or do they need to be specific? I noticed that some are VGA, others DVI, etc.

Also what should I look out for in a USB hub.

I'm looking to spend the minimum to see if he takes to it. Also any starter books that would be suitable as both parents are stupid.

Comment: Welcome... "shopping list" type questions are generally frowned upon, so this may get closed quickly!

Answer (score 4):

Any monitor with a HDMI input should work with the Raspberry Pi. If your monitor has a DVI input, a HDMI to DVI adapter will be required.

I bought a used Dell monitor and I use a DVI --> HDMI cable to connect to my Raspberry Pi. You should look into a powered USB hub. The Raspberry Pi's power supply may not be sufficient to drive all USB powered devices.

> Also any starter books that would be suitable as both parents are
>   stupid.

You are the smartest parent because you bought a Raspberry Pi for your son. I don't know your son's age. The Raspberry Pi has got a scratch programming interface especially to teach programming to kids. If your son has some basic programming experience, this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071807837) might be helpful to work independently.

Comment: Great, noticed some monitors were only VGA so ignore those.

Comment: @dave: I was able to get HDMI --> DVI working. I have not tried VGA to HDMI on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @dave if your Screen is VGA, there are also HDMI -> VGA converters!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any monitor will work, but you may need to play with your output in the configuration file (`force hdmi`) if it is really old.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and welcome to the StackExchange community! :) Your answer is probably right but it may be better with explanations about where is the configuration file, what to modify, etc. or at least a link (not really recommended but still better than nothing). Even if dave didn't asked for, it could help other users looking for a solution to the problem of old hardware.